# When trying access event.target.$something always return 'undefined'

Tags: reactjs, events, scroll, event-handling, infinite-scroll

Im trying to set an event handler for scroll,
I found in many sources the simple line of:

> const bottom = e.target.scrollHeight - e.target.scrollTop ===
>   e.target.clientHeight;

but for some reason , its always return undefined:

```
  handleScroll = (e) => {
    console.log('inside hanglescroll');
    const bottom = e.target.scrollHeight - e.target.scrollTop === e.target.clientHeight;
    console.log(e.target.scrollHeight);   **print undefined!!**
    console.log(e.target.scrollTop);     **print undefined!!**
    console.log(e.target.clientHeight);   **print undefined!!**
    if (bottom) {
      console.log('we are in the bottom');
     }
  }


  componentDidMount() {
    window.addEventListener('scroll',this.handleScroll.bind(this));
  }
```

Thank you!!

Answer (score 3):

This happens because in this case `e.target === document`, which is [`Document`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document), not DOM element. While DOM element is reachable as `document.documentElement`.

This should work:

```
  handleScroll = (e) => {
    const el = e.target.documentElement;
    const bottom = el.scrollHeight - el.scrollTop === el.clientHeight;
    if (bottom) {
      console.log('we are in the bottom');
     }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    window.addEventListener('scroll',this.handleScroll);
  }
```

Notice that `.bind(this)` doesn't do anything with arrow functions and isn't needed. It's either an arrow or prototype method with `bind`.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally,it should be `document` instead of `e`.Don't need to bind the arrow function,because it implicitly the binds the callee context.

```
  handleScroll = (e) => {
        let scrollTop = (document.documentElement && document.documentElement.scrollTop) || 
         document.body.scrollTop;
        let scrollHeight = (document.documentElement && 
        document.documentElement.scrollHeight) || document.body.scrollHeight;
        let clientHeight = document.documentElement.clientHeight || window.innerHeight;
        let scrolledToBottom = Math.ceil(scrollTop + clientHeight) >= scrollHeight;
        console.log(scrolledToBottom);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  componentDidMount = () => {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', this.handleScroll, true);
  };

  handleScroll = () => {
    const end =
      document.documentElement.scrollHeight -
        document.documentElement.scrollTop ===
      document.documentElement.clientHeight;

    if (end) {
      console.log('e,', end);
    }
  };
```